# What does ::$1 mean in an htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I've been browsing the symfony2 framework source. In the htaccess file for their example website, I found the `%{REQUEST_URI}::$1` written as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
```

The comment above that rule explains

> The following rewrites all other queries to the front controller. The condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to allow proper resolution of the app.php file; it will work in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size fits all solution.

However, that doesn't explain the `::$1` or `::\2`.

Are they backreferences? If not, what are they? What is their purpose?

Comment: totally agree, it's much better worded and concise, thanks trojansdestroy!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have encountered almost the same htaccess file in my Zend project, and here are my thoughts and hope it helps.

The htaccess file (located at the Zend project directory, same as index.php) says

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Suppose Zend is installed at http://mydomain.tld/zend (let's call it yourdomain later on)
and we are requesting `yourdomain/mycontroller/myaction`

**Therefore `%{REQUEST_URI}` will be `/zend/mycontroller/myaction`.**

Note that `$1`, which is the pattern in the `RewriteRule` directive in the htaccess context [1], "will initially be matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that led the server to the current `RewriteRule` (e.g. `app1/index.html` or `index.html` depending on where the directives are defined)".

**Therefore `$1` will be `mycontroller/myaction`.**

And `%{REQUEST_URI}::$1` will be `/zend/mycontroller/myaction::mycontroller/myaction`.

The above string will be matched against `^(/.+)(.+)::\2$`. Note that for the two capturing groups in round braces i.e., `(/.+)(.+)` before `::` many combinations can match that. For example:

Group 1: `/z`

Group 2: `end/mycontroller/myaction`

or

Group 1: `/zend/mycontroller/myactio`

Group 2: `n`

and anything in between is a valid match. In fact, the most interesting one would be

Group 1: `/zend/`

Group 2: `mycontroller/myaction`

which (is the only case that) makes backreference `\2` (after `::`) to the second group a match.

In this case, `/zend/` will be stored in the environment variable `BASE` which is what the first `RewriteRule` does. The `%1` refers to the first matched string in `RewriteCond` which is `/zend/`.

Looking at the second `RewriteRule`, it is clear that why there is a need for this. As `index.php` can only be found in `/zend/index.php`, we need to add `/zend/` in front of `index.php`.

Here we assume to use the URL-path as Substitution for the second `RewriteRule` directive. Refer to [1] and search for "A DocumentRoot-relative path to the resource to be served" under the RewriteRule Directive section.

All the above leave the query string unchanged/untouched. It is up to `index.php` how to parse the query string (as well as the URI).

**Lastly goes the case where Zend is installed at the domain root.**

- `%{REQUEST_URI}` will be `/mycontroller/myaction`.
- `$1` will be `mycontroller/myaction`.

The string to be matched by RewriteCond will be `/mycontroller/myaction::mycontroller/myaction`.

This time the second group in `(/.+)(.+)` will never match `mycontroller/myaction` as there needs to be at least one letter following the initial backslash for the first group, making the second group as close as `ycontroller/myaction` but not exactly `mycontroller/myaction` so there cannot be a match.

As a result, the first `RewriteRule` is not used. The `BASE` enviornment variable will not be set, and when the second RewriteRule uses it, it will simply be empty.

**References**

[1] http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: that actually sounds a pretty good deduction of what it does and how it works, I'm going to look at it in more detail, but I think you've got it.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

The `$1` in `%{REQUEST_URI}::$1` references the matched string of the `RewriteRule` directive, i.e., the matched string of `.*` in `^(.*)`. So `%{REQUEST_URI}::$1` is expanded to the requested URI path as supplied by the user, and the current internal URI path and query, separated by `::`.

The pattern `^(/.+)(.+)::\2$` is used to find a prefix (first capturing group) which makes the remaining part match the part behind the `::` (`\2` is a back reference to the matched string of the second capturing group of the pattern).

If such a match is found, the prefix is stored in the environment variable `BASE` (`[E=BASE:%1]`, where `%1` references the matched string of the previous successful `RewriteCond` pattern match).

Comment: ahhh, thank you for the explanation, I had an idea that it was figuring out it's "installed" directory in the system, relative to the document root.  So if you install it at "domain.com/" then $1 will be "/" and $2 will be "empty", but if you install it at "domain.com/install/directory/application/route", $1 will be "/install/directory/" and $2 will be "/application/route"

if you understand why, could you clarify that for me? cause I'm not 100% sure why they want two capture groups, you could expand your answer a bit with an example?

Comment: hmm, I think I misunderstood what it was doing, in fact, it appears to just set an environment variable with / no matter what url I open, I created a test site and it never changes, it's always /.  I thought they had discovered a way to automatically assign the document root of a website without manually assigning it.